# Can't knit to pdf using the {gtsummary} package in r

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, gtsummary

I am unable to knit to pdf using the [gtsummary](https://github.com/ddsjoberg/gtsummary) package. Here's a reprex:

```
library(gtsummary)
reg <- lm(hp ~ cyl, mtcars)
tbl_regression(reg, intercept = TRUE)
```

This error only occurs when I use the `intercept = TRUE` argument. If I delete the `intercept` argument, I can knit to pdf just fine.

The error message that follows after attempting to knit to pdf:

```
output file: reprex.knit.md

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...al \expandafter \let \cmrsideswitch 
                                                  \@tempa \fi \fi 
l.129 (Intercept)
                  & -51 & -102, -0.03 & 0.050 \\ 

Error: LaTeX failed to compile reprex.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See reprex.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

And finally, my `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] gtsummary_1.2.6

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.3       pillar_1.4.3     compiler_3.6.2   tools_3.6.2      digest_0.6.24    checkmate_2.0.0  evaluate_0.14   
 [8] lifecycle_0.1.0  tibble_2.1.3     nlme_3.1-142     gtable_0.3.0     lattice_0.20-38  pkgconfig_2.0.3  rlang_0.4.4     
[15] rstudioapi_0.11  commonmark_1.7   yaml_2.2.1       xfun_0.12        dplyr_0.8.4      stringr_1.4.0    knitr_1.28      
[22] sass_0.1.2.1     generics_0.0.2   vctrs_0.2.3      grid_3.6.2       tidyselect_1.0.0 glue_1.3.1       R6_2.4.1        
[29] rmarkdown_2.1    tidyr_1.0.2      purrr_0.3.3      ggplot2_3.2.1    magrittr_1.5     backports_1.1.5  scales_1.1.0    
[36] htmltools_0.4.0  assertthat_0.2.1 gt_0.1.0         colorspace_1.4-1 stringi_1.4.6    lazyeval_0.2.2   munsell_0.5.0   
[43] broom_0.5.4      crayon_1.3.4
```

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the error with the example code you gave (Ubuntu 19.10 , Tex Live and R version 3.6.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to re-create the error on my machine. gtsummary uses the gt package by default to print the tables. Currently, gt supports HTML output, with LaTeX and RTF planned for the future. While you can specify PDF and RTF output for R markdown (and it often works and looks great!), the feature is not yet finalized.

You can also use {huxtable} to output the tables from gtsummary in R markdown via LaTeX..

```r
library(gtsummary)
reg <- lm(hp ~ cyl, mtcars)
tbl_regression(reg, intercept = TRUE) %>%
  as_hux_table()
```

Hope this helps!